# Delphi error F2051 on FMX.Helpers.Android unit when compiling for Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have a program that is reporting the following error when compiled for Android:

> [DCC Fatal Error] Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText.pas(17085): F2051 Unit FMX.Helpers.Android was compiled with a different version of Androidapi.JNIBridge.TJavaArray`1.GetItem

Any clue what this can be?

Note: I only have 1 `FMX.helpers.android.pas` file on my entire computer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your build configuration. If you are using a batch, it might be the trouble.

Clean the project by clicking in the project in project group.

If necessary delete output folder that has all .dcu files previously generated.

Then rebuild your project.

Comment: Also, check on your seachpath if you have any path to an old embarcadero setting like $(BDS)\source\rtl\android. If so, remove it.